# Remove all matching words

Tags: regex

I have this text:

```
"headword":"final"
"headword":"family name"
"headword":"penultimate"
```

I want to get only

```
final
family name
penultimate
```

I tried several regex but no luck to make it work, 
this will do the opposite

```
 (\W*(headword))\W*
```

I tried to negate using [^] does not work

Comment: Why even use a regex? Splitting on the `:` and taking the second index of the result should get you what you want for less computational cost.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
(?:"\w+":)"([^"]+)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/KLPP22/1

`[^"]+` - matches all characters except `"`

The needed values are in the *1st Capturing Group*

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

`.+"."(.+)"`

https://regex101.com/r/BwFP0z/1

Answer (score 0):

```
// str is the text you want to replace and first captured group is replaced with whole capture.
str.replace(/(?:"headword":")([^"]+)(?:")/gmi, '$1');
```

http://codepen.io/asanhix/pen/XpGoKg?editors=0012